# How to solve double mysql query with user inputs?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get back from query a level status. In query i'm sending 2 user inputs: body_weight and lift_weight. So task is: get the nearest value of body weight and than the nearest lift_weight to user input and print out level
EXAMPLE: user body weight = 54 kg and his lift weight is 60 kg and this is make him INTERMEDIATE.

[image: My database]

i was trying somehting with union but it is wrong in MariaDB:

```
 SELECT * FROM `sila`.`benchpress` WHERE `body_weight`= ABS(body_weight- 54) LIMIT 4 
 UNION 
 SELECT lift_weight FROM `sila`.`benchpress` WHERE `lift_weight`= ABS(lift_weight- 84) LIMIT
```

I Just want that one good row and use in my java expert system

Comment: Please define what you mean by "nearest" value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> get the nearest value of body weight and than the nearest lift_weight to user input and print out level

This suggests `order by` and limit:

```
select bp.*
from `sila`.`benchpress` bp
order by abs(body_weight - 54), 
         abs(lift_weight - 84)
limit 1;
```